# Combobox on mobile opens the keyboard even if allowFreeform={false} and autoComplete="off"

Tags: fluent-ui, fluentui-react

After the combobox is clicked the menu doesn't expand, only the keyboard appears, then with a second tap the options are shown. The keyboard is still open and if y try to close it the options also disapears.

I have this options

```
allowFreeform={false}
autoComplete="off"
```

And tried

```
allowFreeform={true}
autoComplete="on"

allowFreeform={false}
autoComplete="on"

allowFreeform={false}
autoComplete="off"
```